# python telegram bot - how to get bot role for private channels?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

bot.get_chat_administrators seems to return ChatMember instance for public channels. I need role of my bot in private channels.

Answer (score 0):

if send message works bot should be admin in the channel.
https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_message

but in my case it didn't work. so I referred to official api:

```
import requests
from telegram import Bot

TOKEN = "YOUR_TOKEN"
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
def send_message_to_private(chat_id, text):
    api = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={text}'
    response = requests.get(api).json()
    return  response['result']
```